# Using python ctypes to call io_submit in Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, stack, ctypes

I'm trying to call io_submit using python ctypes.
The code I'm writing is supposed to work on both 32 and 64-bit Intel/AMD architectures, but here I'll focus on 64 bits.

I have defined the following:

```
def PADDED64(type, name1, name2):
    return [(name1, type), (name2, type)]

def PADDEDptr64(type, name1, name2): 
    return [(name1, type)]

def PADDEDul64(name1, name2):
    return [(name1, ctypes.c_ulong)]

class IOVec(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("iov_base", ctypes.c_void_p), ("iov_len", ctypes.c_size_t)]

class IOCBDataCommon64(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = PADDEDptr64(ctypes.c_void_p, "buf", "__pad1") + \
        PADDEDul64("nbytes", "__pad2") + \
        [("offset", ctypes.c_longlong), ("__pad3", ctypes.c_longlong), ("flags", ctypes.c_uint), ("resfd", ctypes.c_uint)]

class IOCBDataVector(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("vec", ctypes.POINTER(IOVec)), ("nr", ctypes.c_int), ("offset", ctypes.c_longlong)]

class IOCBDataPoll64(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = PADDED64(ctypes.c_int, "events", "__pad1")

class SockAddr(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("sa_family", ctypes.c_ushort), ("sa_data", ctypes.c_char * 14)]

class IOCBDataSockAddr(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("addr", ctypes.POINTER(SockAddr)), ("len", ctypes.c_int)]

class IOCBDataUnion64(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("c", IOCBDataCommon64), ("v", IOCBDataVector), ("poll", IOCBDataPoll64), ("saddr", IOCBDataSockAddr)]

class IOCB64(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = PADDEDptr64(ctypes.c_void_p, "data" , "__pad1") + \
        PADDED64(ctypes.c_uint, "key", "__pad2") + \
        [("aio_lio_opcode", ctypes.c_short), ("aio_reqprio", ctypes.c_short), ("aio_fildes", ctypes.c_int), ("u", IOCBDataUnion64)]

class Timespec(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("tv_sec", ctypes.c_long), ("tv_nsec", ctypes.c_long)]

class IOEvent64(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = PADDEDptr64(ctypes.c_void_p, "data", "__pad1") + \
        PADDEDptr64(ctypes.POINTER(IOCB64), "obj", "__pad2") + \
        PADDEDul64("res", "__pad3") + \
        PADDEDul64("res2", "__pad4")
```

I have a wrapper class called AIOCommands:

```
class AIOCommands:
    def __init__(self, aioCommandList):
        self.__commandList = aioCommandList
        self.__iocbs = (IOCB64 * len(self.__commandList))()
        for i in range(len(self.__commandList)):
            self.__commandList[i].initialize(self.__iocbs[i])
    def size(self):
        return len(self.__iocbs)
    def getIOCBArray(self):
        return self.__iocbs
```

I have defined the arguments and the return value of io_submit:

```
class Executor:
    def __init__(self, aioLibraryPath):
        self.__aio = ctypes.CDLL(aioLibraryPath)
        self.__aio.io_submit.argtypes = [self.aio_context_t, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(IOCB64))]
        self.__aio.io_submit.restype = ctypes.c_long
```

Now, what should Executor.io_submit body look like? I tried:

```
def io_submit(self, aioContext, aioCommands):
    iocbPtr = ctypes.cast(aioCommands.getIOCBArray(), ctypes.POINTER(self.iocb_t))
    return self.__aio.io_submit(aioContext, aioCommands.size(), ctypes.byref(iocbPtr))
```

But I get a **segmentation fault** whenever the length of aioCommandList is greater than 1.
When the list contains just 1 command, the code works as expected.

Could this be a problem with my structure definitions? I've tried to imitate the definitions in libaio.h (assuming only little-endian architectures will be supported):

```
#if defined(__i386__) /* little endian, 32 bits */
#define PADDED(x, y)    x; unsigned y
#define PADDEDptr(x, y) x; unsigned y
#define PADDEDul(x, y)  unsigned long x; unsigned y
#elif defined(__ia64__) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__alpha__)
#define PADDED(x, y)    x, y
#define PADDEDptr(x, y) x
#define PADDEDul(x, y)  unsigned long x
#elif defined(__powerpc64__) /* big endian, 64 bits */
#define PADDED(x, y)    unsigned y; x
#define PADDEDptr(x,y)  x
#define PADDEDul(x, y)  unsigned long x
#elif defined(__PPC__)  /* big endian, 32 bits */
#define PADDED(x, y)    unsigned y; x
#define PADDEDptr(x, y) unsigned y; x
#define PADDEDul(x, y)  unsigned y; unsigned long x
#elif defined(__s390x__) /* big endian, 64 bits */
#define PADDED(x, y)    unsigned y; x
#define PADDEDptr(x,y)  x
#define PADDEDul(x, y)  unsigned long x
#elif defined(__s390__) /* big endian, 32 bits */
#define PADDED(x, y)    unsigned y; x
#define PADDEDptr(x, y) unsigned y; x
#define PADDEDul(x, y)  unsigned y; unsigned long x
#else
#error  endian?
#endif

struct io_iocb_poll {
    PADDED(int events, __pad1);
};  /* result code is the set of result flags or -'ve errno */

struct io_iocb_sockaddr {
    struct sockaddr *addr;
    int     len;
};  /* result code is the length of the sockaddr, or -'ve errno */

struct io_iocb_common {
    PADDEDptr(void  *buf, __pad1);
    PADDEDul(nbytes, __pad2);
    long long   offset;
    long long   __pad3;
    unsigned    flags;
    unsigned    resfd;
};  /* result code is the amount read or -'ve errno */

struct io_iocb_vector {
    const struct iovec  *vec;
    int         nr;
    long long       offset;
};  /* result code is the amount read or -'ve errno */

struct iocb {
    PADDEDptr(void *data, __pad1);  /* Return in the io completion event */
    PADDED(unsigned key, __pad2);   /* For use in identifying io requests */

    short       aio_lio_opcode; 
    short       aio_reqprio;
    int     aio_fildes;

    union {
        struct io_iocb_common       c;
        struct io_iocb_vector       v;
        struct io_iocb_poll     poll;
        struct io_iocb_sockaddr saddr;
    } u;
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck on this for several hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it is that the **iocbpp** argument to `io_submit()` is an array of pointers to struct iocb.

This seems to be reinforced with the Linux-specific example here: http://voinici.ceata.org/~sana/blog/?p=248 and by the EINVAL error documentation here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/io_submit (array subscripting takes precedence over dereferencing)

What you have provided to `io_submit()` is a reference to an array of struct iocb.  You will surely get a segfault as `io_submit` dereferences bogus memory addresses as it iterates through the iocbpp array.  The first element (index 0) will work fine since there is no memory offset to access it.

**edit**
Another example here: http://www.xmailserver.org/eventfd-aio-test.c

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood the semantics of io_submit. It works now